# how to display warning message for wrong entry of zipcode?

Tags: magento2

how to display warning message for wrong entry of zip/postal code? actually it is default in magento2 but in my case it is not showing any warning message except this("This is a required field.")[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9cvo.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNvwG.png i need warning message like this

[image] this is my case here i'm not getting warning message